# How can I send http request between ECS services by using App Mesh and Cloud Map

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-app-mesh, aws-cloudmap

### What I try to do

- Send a http request from app-gateway to app-backend.
- I've created apps for the purpose. (https://github.com/tbrand/app-mesh-sample)

### What I can't do

- When the app-gateway sends http request to app-backend, it says 'ENOTFOUND'. (DNS lookup failure?)

### Details

- I have two minimum apps (app-gateway and app-backend. written in Node.js) on ECS under the same VPC. They are running well independently.

  - Envoy proxies are injected by ECS console with default configuration.
- I defined an App Mesh which has a router to the backend service.
- AWS Cloud Map is created by ECS. It seems the instances are correctly registered on each service.
- I use 3000 as a listen port for every definitions except ALB. (It uses 80.)

### Architecture

#### ECS

- mymesh (ECS cluster)

  - app-gateway (ECS service. The task definition is injected by envoy proxy.)
  - app-backend (ECS service. The task definition is injected by envoy proxy.)

#### AWS App Mesh

- app-backend.mymesh.local (Virtual service. provider=app-backend (Virtual router))
- app-gateway.mymesh.local (Virtual service. provider=app-gateway (Virtual node))
- app-backend (Virtual router. It has a route to the app-backend (Virtual node).)
- app-backend (Virtual node. service discovery=AWS Cloud Map, namespace=mymesh.local, service name=app-backend)
- app-gateway (Virtual node. service discovery=AWS Cloud Map, namespace=mymesh.local, service name=app-gateway, backend=app-backend.mymesh.local)

#### AWS Cloud Map

- mymesh.local (Namespace)

  - app-backend (Service. It has a instance registered by ECS)
  - app-gateway (Service. It has a instance registered by ECS)

#### Route 53

- mymesh.local (Private host zone. It's assciated with the VPC. It's created when I defined first service on ECS.)

  - app-backend.mymesh.local (A record. The value is the IP address which ECS task is running on.)
  - app-gateway.mymesh.local (A record. The value is the IP address which ECS task is running on.)

#### ALB

- app-gateway (A public endpoint to the app-gateway service. It works well.)

  - app-gateway (A target group. The targets are registered by ECS.)

According to [this sample app](https://github.com/aws/aws-app-mesh-examples), I thought that I could access to the app-backend via `app-backend.mymesh.local` like [this](https://github.com/tbrand/app-mesh-sample/blob/master/app-gateway/app.js#L11).
But it raises the error.

Please tell me if I should tell more details. (I would tell them by text or screenshots.)

How can I make the http request successfully between ECS services with App Mesh?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved by myself. DNS hostnames configuration must be enabled on my VPC configuration.
After enabling it, it works fine. Thanks.